# code error when i run the code in code block compiler

Tags: c++, codeblocks

i download codeblock compiler and run this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 /* my first program in C */
printf("c++ C++!");

 return 0;
}
```

but when i click on run .. in cmd this code display Hello world  instead of `c++ C++!`

any help?

[image]

Comment: Missed to save your changes perhaps?

Comment: i also save the changes

Comment: The active save button indicates you didn't.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem can not be reproduced.

Comment: why you close it as my problem still not solve

Comment: Yeah, but it's your problem.

Comment: so why users post questions in stakoverflow  if users problem is there problem

Comment: @scorpio So if no one else can reproduce this, it's your unique problem actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you clicked **Run** instead of **Build and run**? 
Use **F9** shortcut key for build and run is a good practice. Hope it helps :)